# Scroll a table view to a cell, then flash the cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, selection

I have a table view with a number of cells. When I add a new cell (using a modal view controller) I'd like to show the user the newly added cell. To do this I want to scroll the table view to the new cell, select it and immediately deselect it.

Right now, I'm sending a `deselectRowAtIndexPath` to my table view after a timed interval:

```
- (IBAction)selectRow 
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    [self performSelector:@selector(deselectRow:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:1.0f];
}

- (void)deselectRow:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to do this. It works well, but I don't like relying on a static timer to perform an operation which could sometimes take a different amount of time (e.g. if the table was very long).

**Edit:** Note that `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition` won't cause the `UITableView` delegate methods to get fired. Neither `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` nor `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` will be called. From the docs:

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message, nor will it send `UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` notifications to observers.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewDelegate` is an extension of `UIScrollViewDelegate`. You could implement one of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods and use that to determine when to deselect the row. `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` seems like a good place to start.

Also, I personally find the `performSelector...` methods limiting due to the 1 parameter restrictions. I prefer to use GCD. The code would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)selectRow 
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    //deselect the row after a delay
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the GCD version. Unfortunately the scroll view delegate won't be informed, as the scrolling is not user-initiated. I implemented it to check, but it was only called when I scrolled the table manually.

Comment: You could implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` and check the `contentOffset.y` to see if the cell is visible.